# Git Bash Fatal:Could not read from remote repository

Tags: windows, git, bash, github

So I have a git repo set up on a linux machine and I typed

```
git remote add test git@*****.com:/opt/git/project.git
```

and then I did

```
git init
git add *
git commit  -m 'Blah blah'
```

When I go to do

```
git push remotename
```

I get  `fatal:Could not read from remote repository.`

I know it is a problem on my side, because my friend can on his arch linux machine. I have private ssh keys in a different folder then my git bash and then I have public keys in the git user home folder all set up. I don't know if I need to set up SSH keys somehow with git bash or something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the upstream repo as a remote

```
git remote add remotename git@*****.com:/opt/git/project.git
```

And now do a push

```
git push remotename
```

***PS*** : The step where you ran `git add git@*****.com:/opt/git/project.git` was meaningless, and should have thrown you an error ideally.

Comment: I meant to put I did git remote add sorry.

Comment: @Iramos15 It would still throw an error since you didn't initialize the repo beforehand using `git init`. It would have worked correctly only after you ran `git init`.

Comment: Can you add the remote again and check if that helps?

Comment: i have an initialized repo and have git remoted a few times still nothing

Comment: can you ssh to the server? if no, setup your ssh keys first; If yes, then are there any specific steps (like specifying the key) that you have to follow when doing ssh? if yes, list them in the question.

Comment: i can ssh from my putty folder with the ssh keys but not from the git bash

Comment: Duuuuuude! you tagged the question with linux, when this whole time you were on windows... that's not good... you have managed to waste both our times..

Comment: sorry it sort of had linux and windows those were the suggested tags so i clicked them